# Random Slideshow

Tags: macos, software-rec

Does anyone know of an OS X program that will let my play photos from a particular folder in a random order? iPhoto provides this functionally but I don't necessarily want to add all these photos to my library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something very simple that is already available on your mac :

Screen saver with your personal photos folder :

[image]

[image]

In addition you can use hot corners to start the screen saver. It has also pretty nice transition and traveling effects.

Answer (score 0):

Super old question but in 2023 it is still relevant... That is exactly why I've developed **Slideshower** - a simple & lightweight macOS app to run full-screen, randomized photo slideshows. As of Dec 2023 it's still free ;-)

You can check it out here: https://slideshower.com. Any feedback is more than appreciated!